# Why am I getting an IllegalThreadStateException error in ProcessBuilder --Java?

Tags: java, process, processbuilder, exit-code

This code results in an IllegalThreadStateException runtime error from the line with the if statement:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("\"c:\\[directory]/doer.exe\"").start();
    if(proc.exitValue() == 1)
        System.out.println("Output: 1");
}
```

the executable this is supposed to run specifically has the exit code 1.  What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you want `"\"c:\\[directory]\\doer.exe\""` ?

Answer (score 6):

The javadoc of Process#exitValue describes why it throws the exception:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()

> Throws: IllegalThreadStateException - if the subprocess represented by this Process object has not yet terminated

Use `proc.waitFor()` before the if-statement to wait until the process finishes.

Comment: I had a similar issue to the one described in the question. the proposed solution solved it. This should be marked as the correct answer. Thanks